# MongoDB Yelp-like search engine, location + category

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm creating a Yelp-like app using MongoDB, Express, JS, and Node.  By searching, I was able to find how to search for multiple fields of a campus schema (campuses, restaurants, barbershops, name).  I now want to refine the search by location (i.e. restaurants/business in Los Angeles) and I need help doing this. Here is what I tried so far:

I'm tried the $and/$or commands for Mongo.  When I just use $or, I am able to search by name or location.

**Route**

```
router.get("/campus", function(req, res){
var noMatch = null;
if(req.query.search){
    const regex = new RegExp(escapeRegex(req.query.search), 'gi');
    Campus.find({$and:[
        {$or: [{name: regex}, {location:regex},  {food: regex},  
               {cost: regex}, {category:regex}]} ,
        {$or: [{location: regex}]},
        ]},
        function(err, allCampuses){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        if(allCampuses.length < 1){
            req.flash("error", "No campus match that search, please try 
                       again.");
            return res.redirect("back");
            // noMatch = "No campus match that query, please try again.";
        }
        res.render("campus/index", {campus:allCampuses, currentUser: 
                                    req.user, noMatch: noMatch});
    }
})
} else{
//get all campus from DB
Campus.find({}, function(err, allCampuses){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("campuses/index", {campus:allCampuses, currentUser: 
                    req.user, noMatch: noMatch});
    }
})
}
})
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
   <header id="coverImage" class="jumbotron img-fluid">
       <div class="container">
            <h1>Welcome to CampusFinder</h1>
            <p>View our hand-picked Campuses</p>
            <p>
               <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lrg" href="/bizs/new">Add New Campus</a>
           </p>
            <p>
             <form action="/campuses" method="GET" class="form-inline">
                 <div class="form-group" > 
                    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="campuses 
                                          search" class="form-control">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn default">
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="location">Location</label>
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Florida">
                 </div>
             </form>
            </p>
       </div>
    </header>
```

I expect the output to work like Yelp. When I select the location and search for a campus, the campuses of that city will populate.

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. It's just not working.  I would search for a city that I have in the database and the search will come up with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should exclude the `{location:regex}` from the first condition and use another parameter to capture input location to give to the second clause of AND.

```
  {
    $and: [
      {
        $or: [
          { name: regex },
          { food: regex },
          { cost: regex },
          { category: regex }
        ]
      },
      { location: locationRegex }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: It didn't work. The searches are coming up empty.  This is the regex function I am calling in my first code:

`function escapeRegex(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
};`